# I need help in making my post-comment page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to display a comment button which toggles a div that contains the textbox and submit comment button, but the problem I am facing is that the comments div of the first post toggles properly on click but the rest don't work
My code-

```
$("#comment").click(function(){

var class = $(this).attr("class");
var count = $("#text").size();
$(".comments"+class).slideToggle(100);
if (count === 0) {
    $(".comments").append("<br><input type='text' id='text' class='comment'/><input type='submit' value='Comment' id='login' />");
}
else{

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one element with the id of comment. Try switching that to a show-comment class.

Comment: I didn't get what you said. Please can you explain it a little

Comment: You probably have multiple buttons with the id of 'comment'. You cannot access them all with this selector. You should use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because with $("#comment").click(function(){ ... you only pick the first element with the ID 'comment' - but i guess, you have several posts, right? :) So make it a class instead!